# How to update a document with existing attachments?

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to update a document's data but not an existing attached image in the document unless the user has selected a new one.

How do I copy the existing image and place it in the new document object?

```
function updateInspection() {

console.log('updateInspection started');

var data = $('#inspectionForm').serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj[item.name] = item.value;
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(' docID: ' + data._id);
console.log(' docREV: ' + data._rev);

if (!$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]) {

    console.log(' Get doc Attachment First!');

    local_db.get(data._id,{attachments: true}, function(err, doc) { 
       if (err) { 
          return console.log(err); 
       } else { 

          console.log('doc._attachments: ' +doc._attachments.cover_image.content_type);

          data._attachments = doc._attachments; // THIS IS NOT WORKING
       } 
    });
}

if ($('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]) {

    console.log(' Add/Update Cover Image Attachment!');

    cover_image_name = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name;
    console.log(' cover_image_name: ' + cover_image_name);
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]'); 
    var file = $('#coverImage').prop('files')[0];

    data[ "_attachments" ] = {
      "cover_image": {
        "content_type": "image/jpg",
        "data": file
      }
    };
}

local_db.put(data).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
  console.log('Successfully posted '+result.id);
  console.log('New_rev '+result.rev);
  $("input#_rev").val(result.rev);

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `db.get()` with `{attachments: false}` then you can re-insert that same document with whatever non-attachment changes you want. The attachments will be marked as `stub:true` in the JSON, which PouchDB interprets as "aha, I can just check the checksum, and I don't need to re-insert the whole attachment blob."

So in your case, just do `db.get('id', {attachments: false})` if the blob is unchanged, and then re-insert that same document with the changes.

Comment: I found this to help with that:

for(var k in data) doc[k]=data[k];